# If $w = \int_{x}^{x^2} {exp(-u^2)}du$. Find $\frac{dw}{dx}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

If $w = \int_{x}^{x^2} {exp(-u^2)}du$. Find $\frac{dw}{dx}$.

Hi, I am assuming that I need to find antiderivative first and then find the derivative but I am not sure how I should start.

Comment: um what is w???

Comment: Let $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}e^{-u^2}du$. Then your function $w(x)=\int_{0}^{x^2}e^{-u^2}du-\int_{0}^{x}e^{-u^2}du=f(x^2)-f(x)$. Therefore $w'(x)=2xf'(x^2)-f'(x)$. Now use that $f'(x)=e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Sorry about that! Just fixed it

Comment: This is a simple application of something we usually call [Leibniz Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).  The advantage is that you will not need "to find [the] antiderivative first".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $w(x)=\displaystyle \int_x^{x^2}e^{-u^2} \,du$, the $2$nd Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us that $\boxed{w'(x)=e^{-x^4}(2x)-e^{-x^2}}$.

---

More generally, if $w(x)=\displaystyle \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(u)\,du$, $2$nd FTC tells us $w'(x)=f(b(x))b'(x)-f(a(x))a'(x)$.

Why? We assume that the  antiderivative of $f(u)$ is $F(u)$.

Then, we have that $w(x)=F(b(x))-F(a(x))$.

Pretty straightforward. Now, differentiating and applying Chain Rule gives us $F'(b(x))b'(x)-F'(a(x))a'(x)$. Now, we remember that the derivative of $F(u)$ is $f(u)$.

Boom! $w'(x)=f(b(x))b'(x)-f(a(x))a'(x)$.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot!